# Matlab load function performance

Tags: matlab

I am observing a very low performance of the `load` function:

```
tic; v = load('file.txt', 'ascii'); toc
Elapsed time is 462.528007 seconds.
```

I am getting ~460 seconds performance repeatedly.
File size is 5.9 GB and it is a 4-column data, which looks like this:

```
00319929  00786575  00320101  00786305
00319929  00786575  00320107  00786305
00319929  00786575  00320113  00786306
00319929  00786575  00320120  00786306
and so on
```

Regular copy of same file takes about 2 seconds:

```
>> time dd if=file.txt  of=/dev/null bs=1024k
5669+1 records in
5669+1 records out
5945005371 bytes (5.9 GB) copied, 1.28557 seconds, 4.6 GB/s

real    0m1.287s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m1.286s
```

So it is not a file system issue.

Is it normal that `load` function is so slow?

Comment: I'm not surprised that loading 6 Gigs of data in the Matlab workspace takes a while.

Comment: Copying a file is not the same as storing all of that data in memory. Is `textscan` any faster than `load`? And do you need to read it in as strings or do you want to convert the data to integers (i.e., `'00319929'` becomes `319929`)?

Comment: No surprise to me. Loading a file is more than streaming it off a disk. BTW: Loading 7k .mat files (200MB) takes me about 180 seconds.

Comment: Your `dd` measurement is misleading.  Even PCIe-connected SSDs don't sustain a 4.6 GB/s transfer rate.  (And the usual storage busses such as SATA and SAS cap out even lower)

Comment: I am reading from a Panasas (high performance parallel storage) drive. So transfer rate is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html), which may be faster and can let you convert the data as you read it in, thus saving memory:

```
fid = fopen('file.txt');
v = textscan(fid,'%s%s%s%s'); % strings
%v = textscan(fid,'%d%d%d%d','CollectOutput',true); v = v{1}; % uint32
%v = textscan(fid,'%f%f%f%f','CollectOutput',true); v = v{1}; % double
fclose(fid);
```